# internet connection sharing between 2 computers

Tags: internet, arch-linux, connection-sharing

Sorry, I am stuck on this. I tried [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sharing_PPP_Connection) and some other wiki, no luck. I have 2 ethernet cards, one with internet connection (over pppoe) and I try to connect the other computer to internet thru the second card. No luck! (Archlinux,manjaro,archbang; same from all). I remember that over wifi it was easy (laptop is fried now, so no wifi available anymore). Thanks for any time you spend trying to help me.

Comment: The Arch Wiki is generally very clear and correct. Can you say which part fails?

Comment: The second computer report „connected” but no access to internet. I tryed both dhcp (via dnsmasq) and fixed ip. Same result. The main computer - the one connected to internet - don't share a thing (iptables MASQUERADE,allow and so on). And yes, is the first time when I don't find answer in arch wiki. Must be something on my comp